# undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite()

Tags: boost, clion

I want to run a unit test on a simple function, but I am having a problem with Boost. I am using CLion now. Here is my code:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include"testfunction.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( square_test )
{
    BOOST_REQUIRE(testfunction(2)==3);

}
```

But I keep getting the result like this:

```
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_66_0/boost/test/unit_test_suite.hpp:383: undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite()'

C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_66_0/boost/test/unit_test_suite.hpp:383:(.text+0x54): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite()'
```

I tried to make a lot of adjustments to fix the problem like include a dynamic link. Is there something wrong with my boost installation? Thank you so much for the help.